# Installing docker compose v2 via docker-compose-plugin

Tags: apt, docker

I have installed `docker-ce`, `docker-compose` and the `docker-compose-plugin` package on Ubuntu 22.04 from the Docker apt repository, following the [official instructions](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/linux/), but when I type `docker compose` on the command line all I get is this:

```
docker: 'compose' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
```

According to `docker plugin ls`, no plugin has been installed. Any clues?

Some additional information:

- bash-completion does suggests `compose` as a possible subcommand
- There is a working `docker-compose` executable in  `/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/`
- The output of `dpkg -l | grep docker` is as follows:

```
    ii  docker-buildx-plugin                                        0.10.2-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy                                    amd64        Docker Buildx cli plugin.
    ii  docker-ce                                                   5:23.0.1-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy                                  amd64        Docker: the open-source application container engine
    ii  docker-ce-cli                                               5:23.0.1-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy                                  amd64        Docker CLI: the open-source application container engine
    ii  docker-ce-rootless-extras                                   5:23.0.1-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy                                  amd64        Rootless support for Docker.
    ii  docker-compose-plugin                                       2.16.0-1~ubuntu.22.04~jammy                                    amd64        Docker Compose (V2) plugin for the Docker CLI.
    ii  docker-scan-plugin                                          0.23.0~ubuntu-jammy                                            amd64        Docker scan cli plugin.
```

Comment: Hi Aldo, 1) please edit your question and add the result of `dpkg -l | grep docker` 2) how did you install docker itself ?

Comment: Hi @dummyuser, thank you for answering. I installed docker via apt from the repository https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu following the instruction on the webpage mentioned above.

Comment: Please add output of `docker info`, `docker version` and `snap list` ..

Comment: Thank you @ArturMeinild, you pointed me in the right direction! In the output of `docker info` there was the line 

```
WARNING: Plugin "/home/aldo/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose" is not valid: failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /home/aldo/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose: permission denied
```

For some reason that file was a text file with only "Not Found" in it. After I got rid of it `docker compose` started working, and the output of `docker info` now points to the plugins in `/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/`

Comment: That's good to hear. Please post your findings as an answer, as it might help others. Thanks! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examination of the output of `docker info` led me to the solution to the problem. It did indeed contain the line:

```
WARNING: Plugin "/home/aldo/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose" is not valid: failed to fetch metadata: fork/exec /home/aldo/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose: permission denied
```

I'm not sure what might have created it, but in the directory `~/.docker/cli-plugins/` there was a `docker-compose` text file, only containing the words "Not Found". Simply deleting it solved my problem, and now docker finds the default path to the plugin executable `/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose`.

Comment: OMG this is a BIG saver, couldn't figure it out, THANKS!